# Determining subgroups of a finite field and their elements

Tags: finite-fields

I'm studying cryptography and while reading some lecture notes I found the following:

$F$*<sub>37</sub> has subgroups of order 2 ({2<sup>0</sup> , 2<sup>18</sup>}), 3 ({2<sup>0</sup> , 2<sup>12</sup> , 2<sup>24</sup>}), 4, 6, 9, 12, and 18.

1. How to determine that the subgroups are of order 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, and 18?
2. How to determine the elements of those subgroups? (for example ({2<sup>0</sup> , 2<sup>18</sup>}) in the first one.) I know in this one that the base is 2 because the field generator is 2, but where did those powers come from?

Thank you.

Comment: are you acquainted with the Sylow's Subgroups Theorems?

Comment: Sylow is overkill for abelian groups. @janmarqz

Comment: Did you miss that there was an element of order $36$? @OneZ

Comment: Also, $2^0$ does not have order $2$. It has order $1$.

Comment: I'll read Sylow's Subgroups Theorems.
I copied the text from professor's notes, so I don't know if he missed an element of order 36.

Comment: Your teacher is applying the following general fact. Given a cyclic grop of order $n$, generated by $g$, it has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for any divisor of $n$. That subgroup is generated by $g^{n/d}$, so its elements are $g^0,g^{n/d}, g^{2n/d},\ldots,g^{(d-1)n/d}$. Here $n=36$,$g=2$ and $d$ varies.

Comment: And I agree with Thomas. This is way more elementary than Sylow. No need for you to go there at this point.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki, I was kinda lost. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use too much information!

You are trying to study the cyclic group of 36 elements and you have chosen a generator of the group. Once you know this, the fact it originated from a finite field doesn't matter at all -- you should ignore that piece of information entirely, and just focus on the fact you're studying a cyclic group.